# TCategoryPanel: How to add controls to header region?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I've got a `TCategoryPanel` descendant and would like to add several controls to its header region, like a `TComboBox` and a `TButton` for instance.

I took a look at the `TCustomCategoryPanel` codes and from what I understood it moves controls added to it into its internal `FPanelSurface` container using a message handler `TCustomCategoryPanel.CMControlListChanging` for `CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGING`.

I created a similar message handler in my descendant:

```
interface

// ...

TElementsCategoryPanel = class(TCategoryPanel)
  // ...
private
  FObservationTypeSelector: TComboBox;

  procedure CMControlListChanging(var Message: TCMControlListChanging);
    message CM_CONTROLLISTCHANGING;
  // ...
end;

implementation

// ...

constructor TElementsCategoryPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  // ...

  FObservationTypeSelector := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  FObservationTypeSelector.Name := 'ObservationTypeSelector';
  FObservationTypeSelector.Parent := Self; // *

  // ...
end;

procedure TElementsCategoryPanel.CMControlListChanging(
  var Message: TCMControlListChanging);
begin
  if not (Message.ControlListItem^.Control = FObservationTypeSelector) then // *
    inherited;
end;
```

Using breakpoints `*` to step through, the logic works. When `FObservationTypeSelector.Parent := Self` is set in the `constructor`, my `CMControlListChanging` is being called:

If `Message.ControlListItem^.Control` is not my `FObservationTypeSelector` combobox, it will call its parent function via `inherited`.

If `Message.ControlListItem^.Control` **IS** my `FObservationTypeSelector` combobox, it will do nothing, meaning it will keep its assignment from the constructor.

But the code does not seem to have an effect. Afterwards when positioning my combobox after the panel is shown, setting it to `FObservationTypeSelector.Top := 0` it remains bound inside the `FPanelSurface` container, being placed under the header, instead inside of it, as expected.

Current state:

[image]

Desired state:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your problem here is due to fact that `TCategoryPanel` header section is in non client window area. There is no simple way of adding controls to it. Take a look at articles like [How can I put a button on a form's caption bar?](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/forms6.htm) Another solution would be to reimplement `TCategoryPanel` behavior, removing NC area and adding panel control at top that would serve as header. Even though that solution would involve some work, it would be more flexible and bullet proof.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you. Indeed. You are right. I completely overlooked the `WMNC...` parts of the code and thought it would be so easy to intercept that `CMControlListChanging` handler. I took a look at their code again and did some tests. Guess I need to do it myself then ...